# Laravel 7.x - Pass parameter in url to register form

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to pass email adress as parameter in url to register page.

I tried `http://myapp.test/register?email=jonhsnow@myapp.com` but email wasn't filled in form.

I don't know if Laravel protec this url. How can I do this? Is there another way?

Regards

Comment: Do you just add the parameter to the url or do you have code in place to also handle that parameter and set email accordingly?!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You have controller, so you can get the param as `$request->email;` & pass it to your blade (form input field)

Comment: Can you show how you are writing routes in web your web.php?

Comment: @kerbh0lz I get the email address from another form and I would like to make life easier to my users and avoid that filled this field again. I want Just put email address automatically in registration form.

Comment: @Kuldeep is default auth rote `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't fill the email input field by itself, you will have to do it manually.

You can use the `request()` helper and populate the input like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email', request('email')) }}" required>
```

This way it will populate the input when you provide it as a parameter in the URL, and it will keep the value when there is a validation error with `old()`.

From the docs:

[request()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-request)

> The request function returns the current request instance or obtains
> an input item:

```
$request = request();

$value = request('key', $default);
```

[old()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-old)

> The old function retrieves an old input value flashed into the
> session:

```
$value = old('value');

$value = old('value', 'default');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your controller to pass the email string. Or pass the entity that contains the email. If you pass an entity, use `$YourEntity->getEmail()` in your webpage to get the email you need

Comment: the email address come from another application I need pass by url...